# Как выполнить bash скрипт по имени в терминале?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы не пришлось указывать путь к скрипту, а просто написать его название в терминале и он вызывался?

**Пример**

Сейчас надо делать так:

```
sh home/user/test.sh
```

Хочу вызывать так:

```
test
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

довольно удобным решением может быть создание каталога с именем, например, `bin`, внутри своего домашнего каталога:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
```

чтобы можно было запускать исполняемые файлы из этого каталога по имени, достаточно добавить путь к нему в переменную окружения `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

эту команду, чтобы не выполнять её в каждом экземпляре оболочки вручную, можно дописать в конец вашего персонального инициализационного файла оболочки, который носит название `.shellrc`, где *shell* — имя используемой вами оболочки (его можно узнать, например, командой `echo $SHELL`). для *bash* это будет:

```
~/.bashrc
```

для *zsh*:

```
~/.zshrc
```

и т.п.

стоит заметить, что довольно часто производить последнюю манипуляцию нет необходимости: при наличии каталога `~/bin` инициализационные скрипты оболочки автоматически добавят его в переменную окружения `$PATH` (см., например, содержимое файла `~/.profile`). проверить просто: создайте каталог, запустите новый процесс оболочки и проверьте содержимое переменной (`echo $PATH`).

---

нужный вам файл надо скопировать в этот каталог под желаемым именем (имя *test*, кстати, не совсем удачное, так как совпадает с именем встроенной команды оболочки):

```
$ cp ~/test.sh ~/bin/test
```

и присвоить бит исполнимости:

```
$ chmod +x ~/bin/test
```

в случае, если это скрипт, требующий обработки каким-нибудь интерпретатором (в вашем случае интерпретатором `/bin/sh`), то первой строкой скрипта должен быть так называемый [*shebang*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_%28Unix%29), содержащий полный путь к программе-интерпретатору:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно добавить директорию, где лежит скрипт, в $PATH:

**.bashrc**

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/path/to/dir
```

Или создать алиас:

**.bash_aliases**

```
alias test='/path/to/dir/test.sh'
```

Расширение **.sh** необязательно, главное чтобы был шебанг:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Test"
```