# ссылка на скрипт

Tags: python, linux, bash, symlinks

Добрый день.
Написал небольшой скрипт на python.
Вопрос: как сделать так, что бы была возможность запускать скрипт из терминала в независимости от каталога в котором находишься? (на данный момент просто сделал симлинк в корневой каталог)

Comment: Поместить скрипт в один из каталогов, которые есть в переменной окружения `PATH`. Ваш К.О.

Comment: ещё: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/495812/178576