# Исполняемый файл в Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Как на Linux создать исполняемый файл без использования ./

gcc c ключом -o генерирует исполняемый файл который можно использовать только прописывая ./my_program,
но как сделать чтобы его можно было использовать прописывая только имя самой программы "my_program"?

Comment: Bad practice -- `export PATH=$PATH:.`

Comment: Никогда так не делайте. Непоиск по умолчанию исполняемого файла в текущем каталоге — это не просто так сделано.

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440643/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495797/178576)

Comment: Положить в правильное место с помощью `make install` Или копировать в стандартные _$HOME/bin_, _$HOME/.local/bin_.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно положить его в каталог из PATH. Посмотри `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Скопируй его в /usr/local/bin or /usr/sbin or /usr/bin (/usr/local/bin лучший вариант)