# Как загружать собственный скрипт с команды на Linux

Tags: linux, консоль, shell, ос

Я написал свой скрипт на Python. Он запускается как и все скрипты

```
$ cd path/to/script
$ python3 script.py
```

Но я бы хотел запускать его одной командой в терминале. Моя операционная система - Linux. Но мне всё же интересно как это сделать также на других ОС.

Comment: `python3 path/to/script/script.py` ?

Comment: Я вспомнил, это называется alias

Comment: @AlexeyTen, мне такой способ не нравится, поскольку часто ошибки импорта происходят

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495797/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440643/178576) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @wasel, если ошибки импорта, то нужно создать requirements.txt, либо использовать venv и копировать на другие машины

Comment: Запакетируйте так, чтобы можно было устанавливать на другие системы с помощью `pip` или родных пакетных менеджеров.

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавьте в свой скрипт shebang (обязательно первой строкой):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

2. Предоставьте файлу скрипта разрешения на запуск (для linux и MacOS). Примерно так:

```bsh
chmod +x /path/to/your/script.py
```

3. Запустите файл

```bsh
/path/to/your/script.py
```

> Относительно ошибок импорта:
> Прочитаете про virtualenv. Это решит Вашу проблему